# Creating a background in CSS and HTML Only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this background in HTML & CSS - Note: I'm not trying to include the text/logo "Joinnow":

[image]

I've gotten this far show on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uppsLqa/26/

The bottom part is fine but the top part I'm struggling with. For some reason I'm getting:

- angled borders which I need straight
- I can't increase the height of the top.
- I can't curve the corners of the top with border-radis
- The color doesn't match on the top with the body.

Current Code Below:

```
<div class="object"></div>


.object {
    border-bottom-right-radius: .1875em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .1875em;   
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left: .75em;
    margin-right: .75em;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 340px;
    height: 160px;
}
.object:after, .object:before {
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 58%;
    bottom:100%;
    width: 140px;
    height: 800px;
    border-top-left-radius: .1875em;  
    border-top-right-radius: .1875em;  
}

.object:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fafafa;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    height: 60px;
}

.object:before {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative which still uses the :before and :after, but instead of setting the borders of the pseudo-elements, the background color, width and height of each element is set to achieve a similar effect.

**CSS:**

```
.object {
    border-bottom-right-radius: .1875em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .1875em;   
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%);
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left: .75em;
    margin-right: .75em;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 340px;
    height: 160px;
}

.object:after, .object:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 66%;
    bottom: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: .1875em;
    border-top-right-radius: .1875em;
}

.object:after {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 15px;
}

.object:before {
    background-color: #999;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

You can increase the height of the top part by increasing the height value on each pseudo-element. You'll just have to keep in mind that, as it is right now, the :before will always need to have 1px more than the :after when it comes to height.

Also, the alpha values for the linear gradient were changed in order to try and make the color gradient more smooth and even between the top and bottom parts.

**EXAMPLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/58rmrqd9/

Answer (score 2):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/9uppsLqa/28/

Basically you shouldn't need both before and after to create this effect, there is really no need for both in my opinion.

```
.object {
    border-bottom-right-radius: .1875em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .1875em;   
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left: .75em;
    margin-right: .75em;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 340px;
    height: 160px;
}
.object:after {
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    right: -1px;
    bottom:100%;
    width: 140px;
    height: 800px;
    border-top-left-radius: .1875em;  
    border-top-right-radius: .1875em;  
    border-color: #c4c4c4;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I am quite sure that you can set the border-radiuses, heights and widths according to your need, I just set the positioning correctly and removed excessive definitions. I also set the `:after` to start from right instead of with a percent from the left, as changing width or anything will otherwise misalign it.

Comment: Note also that I used explicit hex color value for border (and used border instead of box shadow, since it was only 1px width anyway). Since it is `inset`, I don't really see the point of using box shadow for that anyway, since you have a 100% opaque background color defined there. Considering that the top part doesn't have any gradient.